# is there any array[a,b] syntax in c?

Tags: arrays, c, operators, preprocessor

while reading about the c preprocessor I got something like `array[x=y,x+1]`. I haven't seen this kind of syntax in c before and after searching for many hours I didn't find anything useful.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int arr[] = {5,10,15};
    printf("%d %d %d",arr[0,1]);
    return 0;
}
```

outputs:
`10 1762365112 1769491896`

Can someone elaborate on this?

Comment: Search for "comma operator".

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Comma_operator

Comment: `printf("%d %d %d",arr[0,1]);` Welcome to SO. Don't you get some warning from your compiler that you don't have enough parameters for these 3 format specifiers? Using `%d` without any parameter is causing undefined behaviour.

Comment: Such expressions are seldom the sing of good code.

Comment: What do you `printf("%d %d %d",arr[0,1])` expect to print?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Good code sings. Bad code croaks. :-D

Comment: @DevSolar Sounds like the well-known code quality metric [WTFs/minute](https://i0.wp.com/commadot.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/wtf.png?resize=550%2C433)

Comment: @Gerhardh no it didn't showed any warning.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I was unaware of the comma operator, so I was just checking if `array[0,1]` returns the elements from 0 and 1 index...but it was printing the element with the last specified index and two garbage values with no error.

Comment: What compiler are you using? How cou you compile? You should increase warning level. For GCC or CLang you can use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: @Gerhardh GCC, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Alas, not in C, but in `C++` you could... muah hah hah hah... (Don’t though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of how the comma operator (`,`) works in C, the effect of the (questionable and woefully hard to read) `array[x=y,x+1]` is to first copy the value of `y` into `x` and then use `x+1` as the normal (single dimensional, non-ranged, or whatever you were expecting) index in to the array.

(I do not see the need to discuss your experimental code.)

See the link to documentation of comma operator, as kindly provided in comments by Pignotto:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Comma_operator

Comment: thanks @Yunnosch and everyone else for clearing it out!